# Combobox Item Cell Address

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a ComboBox (ActiveX) and getting List Values from another sheet.

I wonder is that possible to get selected item's cell address?

Comment: Your question seems paradoxical. You must know the cell addresses of the list items at the time of adding them to the Cbx list. Therefoe, if you "forgot" them when you want them back again at a later stage the reason might be that you didn't note them down while you had them, such as in an extra, invisible column in the Cbx itself.

Comment: @Variatus It seems as you mentioned but my goal is like that; I have one sheet which has my lists of documents in one column, and next column it has their filename with their path. I'm choosing my document name from ComboBox. If i know the document's cell address it'll be pretty easy to learn it's filepath with Cell(i,j+1)

Comment: Load the entire file name into an invisible second column in the Cbx at the same time as you load the document names. Then, when you need it, take the name from the invisible extra column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can try something like this.

```
Dim r As Range
With Sheet1.ComboBox1 '/* Sheet1 is where the ComboBox is */
    Set r = Evaluate(.ListFillRange)
    Debug.Print r.Item(.ListIndex + 1).Address
End With
```

To implement it in your situation (as described in comments), you can try:

```
'/* will give you the value right next to the selected value's source cell */
Debug.Print r.Item(.ListIndex + 1).Offser(, 1).Value2
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the listfillrange for a combobox on a userform. Instead just fill the list from an array.

Comment: @jkpieterse I'm not giving recommendation or anything. OP wants to get the address so I give him a possible solution.

Comment: @L42 you're great!

Comment: @jkpieterse why you're not recommended listfillrange ?

Comment: Not sure why, my comment seems to have been removed. Because I have had odd behavior with using ListFillRange in the past.